# Memory mapped IO concept details

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading, operating-system, mmap

I'm attempting to figure out what the best way is to write files in Windows. For that, I've been running some tests with memory mapping, in an attempt to figure out what is happening and how I should organize things...

**Scenario:** The file is intended to be used in a single process, in multiple threads. You should see a thread as a worker that works on the file storage; some of them will read, some will write - and in some cases the file will grow. I want my state to survive both process and OS crashes. Files can be large, say: 1 TB.

After reading a lot on MSDN, I whipped up a small test case. What I basically do is the following:

1. Open a file (`CreateFile`) using `FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING | FILE_FLAG_WRITE_THROUGH`.
2. Build a mmap file handle (`CreateFileMapping`) on the file, using some file growth mechanism.
3. Map the memory regions (`MapViewOfFile`) using a multiple of the sector size (from `STORAGE_PROPERTY_QUERY`). The mode I intend to use is READ+WRITE.

So far I've been unable to figure out how to use these construct exactly (tools like `diskmon` won't work for good reasons) so I decided to ask here. What I basically want to know is: how I can best use these constructs for my scenario?

If I understand correctly, this is more or less the correct approach; however, I'm unsure as to the exact role of `CreateFileMapping` vs `MapViewOfFile` and if this will work in multiple threads (e.g. the way writes are ordered when they are flushed to disk).

1. I intend to open the file once per process as per (1).
2. Per thread, I intend to create a mmap file handle as per (2) for the entire file. If I need to grow the file, I will estimate how much space I need, close the handle and reopen it using `CreateFileMapping`.
3. While the worker is doing its thing, it needs pieces of the file. So, I intend to use `MapViewOfFile` (which seems limited to 2 GB) for each piece, process it annd unmap it again.

Questions:

1. Do I understand the concepts correctly?
2. When is data physically read and written to disk? So, when I have a loop that writes 1 MB of data in (3), will it write that data *after* the unmap call? Or will it write data the moment I hit memory in another page? (After all, disks are block devices so at some point we have to write a block...)
3. Will this work in multiple threads? This is about the calls themselves - I'm not sure if they will error if you have -say- 100 workers.
4. I do understand that (written) data is immediately available in other threads (unless it's a remote file), which means I should be careful with read/write concurrency. If I intend to write stuff, and afterwards update a single-physical-block) header (indicating that readers should use another pointer from now on) - then is it guaranteed that the data is written *prior* to the header?
5. Will it matter if I use 1 file or multiple files (assuming they're on the same physical device of course)?

Comment: Using an MMF is completely inappropriate when you need FILE_FLAG_WRITE_THROUGH and "survive OS crashes".  You have no control over exactly when the MMF changes are flushed to disk.  Don't do it.

Comment: @HansPassant Interesting. I started exploring memory mapping, because I read at some papers that some databases use it for disk IO (and they guarantee 'durability' as per ACID). I also read at the PostgreSQL bugreports (https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/6BCB9D8A16AC4241919521715F4D8BCE4768E3@algol.sollentuna.se ) that they stopped using `FlushFileBuffers` is terrible. So, if both are out - what *do* you suggest here as a solution?

Comment: What's wrong with using WriteFile and ReadFile?  Since you've turned buffering off, it seems to me they provide the guarantees you're looking for, at least as far as the OS is concerned.  (The underlying hardware might or might not respect those guarantees, if you want to be robust to power failures too, but there's not much you can do about it if it doesn't.)

Comment: (Incidentally, I believe MapViewOfFile *will* work for views larger than 2GB, provided of course you build for 64-bit.  Moot in this case since, as Hans says, you won't get the guarantees you need.)

Comment: @HarryJohnston *Nothing* is wrong with `WriteFile`/`ReadFile`; I'm just attempting to figure out the best way to do this. So, let me get this straight: what you guys are basically telling me is that I should stick with them, combined with NO_BUFFERING and WRITE_THROUGH. (Or, don't use these flags and explicitly use `FlushFileBuffers` - whatever performs best). Correct?

Answer (score -3):

Memory mapped files generally work best for READING; not writing. The problem you face is that you have to know the size of the file before you do the mapping.

You say:

> in some cases the file will grow

Which really rules out a memory mapped file.

When you create a memory mapped file on Windoze, you are creating your own page file and mapping a range of memory to that page file. This tends to be the fastest way to read binary data, especially if the file is contiguous.

For writing, memory mapped files are problematic.